# How should I update this database column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So I have a method in my video model:

```
def rank_sum(score, video)
 ...
 ...
end
```

that returns a value that I want to store in my database for the specific video in the `rank_sum` column.

I also order my videos like so:

```
default_scope order('videos.rank_sum')
```

Now my question is how should I update the `rank_sum` column? With a callback? How often should I be updating this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend that you don't create methods that clash with any of the automatically created attributes of your model, as this will interfere with built-in Rails functionality such as form generation.

You could simply rewrite your method as follows:

```
def update_rank_sum(score)
  new_rank = self.rank_sum + score # Or substitute whatever logic is necessary here.
  update_attribute :rank_sum, new_rank
end
```

This will update the value in the database (if necessary) each time the `update_rank_sum` method is called.

If you want to postpone the update of the `rank_sum` value until some later point, you can change the implementation as follows:

```
def update_rank_sum(score)
  new_rank = self.rank_sum + score # Or substitute whatever logic is necessary here.
  self.rank_sum = new_rank
end
```

But remember that you will need to call `save` on the `Video` instance to persist the change to the database.

Updating one field of a single row is likely to take your database in the order of milliseconds, so I wouldn't worry too much about performance unless you know you will need to handle 10s or 100s of changes per second.

Comment: should I use a callback for `update_rank_sum` in the VideoVote model(where my votes are handled)?

Comment: Callbacks don't really work when you need to pass in method arguments. In my first example, the database update is made immediately. In the second, you need to call save on the video after calling update_rank_sum. And yes, `self` refers to the receiver of the method, which will be a `Video` instance if you have defined the method in the `Video` class.

Comment: ok thanks. And when is `update_rank_sum` called? After every user request for a page?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to "when/how often" to update would depend more on the content of the `rank_sum` method. Assuming that method returns the same value unless something about the Video object changes, and has no external dependancies then it would be a good fit to put in a `before_save` callback. However, if the `rank_sum` method has external dependancies, such as maybe reading from a ratings table, then it would be more of a 'business decision' as to how often you would want to update that value in the database, possibly more or less often than a `before_save` callback would trigger it.

**UPDATE**

An example:

```
before_save :set_rank_sum

private

  def set_rank_sum
     self.rank_sum = rank_sum(value1, value2)
  end
```

Comment: cool, can you provide an example of what the callback might look like? I'm not sure how to deal with a callback when the method has parameters...

Comment: I'm making the assumption that rank_sum is an attribute in the database as well as method on the Video object. If that is the case, then anytime the Video object is saved, the rank_sum attribute in the database would be updated to its most recent value.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two choices :

1. Update upon a new vote. Which is probably ok since you can have an index on this field.
2. Update with a cron every 1 hour or so.

Comment: I would assume that updating it upon every new vote might negatively impact performance? Also, I've never used a cron before. Any good sources on how to get started with one?

Comment: I like to use the [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem to do crons with rails applications

Comment: I don't think so really. You're just updating a single sum after all. A cron is pretty easy to you, for more information please take a look at : http://www.codercaste.com/2009/11/24/how-to-backup-mysql-databases-automatically-using-cron/